# what kind of node I need

Tags: nodes

I want to use ethereum php lib and I need to set a node in the script to replace 127.0.0.1 and port 8545. 
What kind of node I use min space and min ram so it will save me money to set the node up
Use a geth node or parity node? In light or fast mode? Or I can use some way to min the space and cost. 
So I can use eth sign and send transaction

Comment: I think there are too many question in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the lowest cost (space and time) try to find a solution that allows you to use https://infura.io/ . This solution will cost money after a certain transaction amount.

Geth / Partiy processing time evaluation (note: it's from parity, more sources required): https://www.parity.io/performance-analysis/

Geth / Parity full-node space consumption: https://etherscan.io/chartsync/chaindefault

Parity light-node space consumption: https://wiki.parity.io/FAQ#light-node

A light node should be sufficient for your case. Would be nice if you can allocate some resources to support the network with a full-node though.

Comment: thanks on the parity wiki link for light node it says the light node only needs 512m ram and 100m space is this true? Can I use this light node in web3 to replace the ip and port 8545? For geth will be similar? Thanks

Comment: @Louis What they claim about their product on their site should be true. The space requirement is realistic as far as I can tell. Try it yourself, the setup process is not that complex. Your light node will run a server on different protocols, on paritiy it's HTTP and WS. Additionally you can use IPC locally. 8545 is usually the default port for the nodes HTTP server. So yes, you can replace the ip and the port in your config reflecting the ip and the port of your local light nodes HTTP server ip and port. It is identical for Geth.